# css styles break on certain url path

Tags: php, html, css

**[www.domain.com/informe](http://www.domain.com/informe)** works fine, but when I enter to **[www.domain.com/informe/:documentid](http://www.domain.com/informe/:documentid)** , all my css styles breaks because the page is looking for the public folder in **[www.domain.com/informe](http://www.domain.com/informe)** and not in the base url.
Also, i have the same problem in localhost.

I am using [Limonade php](https://limonade-php.github.io/) because is lightweight and templating is fast, also deploying it is really fast as well.

This is my index file:

```php
<?php
require_once 'lib/limonade.php';
echo $root_dir;
option('base_path',          $base_path);
option('base_uri',           $base_uri);
option('root_dir',    $root_dir);
option('public_dir',  $root_dir.'/public/');
```

and my default_layout.php file reference the css files like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.css">
```

also my .htacces file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  Options +Indexes
  RewriteEngine on

  # if your app is in a subfolder
  # RewriteBase /my_app/

  # test string is a valid files
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  # test string is a valid directory
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$   index.php?uri=/$1    [NC,L,QSA]
  # with QSA flag (query string append),
  # forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the
  # substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it.
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know about a similar and better microframework for this kind of little projects where I need only to consume an api or know how to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like bellow

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/bootstrap.css">
```

It will then start searching  from the root folder